# Fedora 13 FireFox Error message

Tags: fedora-13

So I have installed Fedora 13 using VMware and fedora works well, but when I click the Firefox to load the webpage, I get an error message that says "server not found" what could be the issue. Its my first time using virtual machines =/

Comment: Vmware player or workstation? What's the network set to be, hostonly, nat or bridged?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the VMware virtual machine is configured to use the default NAT networking, it's probably because Fedora 13 is so far past its end of life (almost 4 years ago) that the default page you are trying to access from Firefox is no longer available. Fedora 13 reached its end of life for updates and support on June 24, 2011. It is vulnerable to the Heartbleed Bug, which is a serious vulnerability in the popular OpenSSL cryptographic software library, so it is recommended to install a currently supported version of Fedora in which this bug has been fixed.

The latest version of Fedora 21, now comes in three editions: Workstation (which is the Fedora desktop edition), Server and Cloud.

Comment: and various respins. Problem may be somewhere else tho